R package serial and garbled data due to clipping of EOL characters
The R package 'serial' provides an interface to serial communication on Linux, MacOS and windows.
In the documentation for the read.serialConnection function, it says: "..end-of-line characters (\n;\r) are clipped according to the settings (translation)."
This can result in unexpected behavior:
A simple serial data stream (e.g a simple arduino script sending the system time in milli seconds since boot) (arduino sketch code below), will result in this kind of output:
... [1] "1558" [1] "1564" [1] "1570" [1] "157615831589" [1] "1595" [1] "1601" [1] "1607" [1] "1613" [1] "1620" [1] "1627" ...
Notice the [1] "157615831589"
By checking the same fundamental issue reading the raw binary data stream revealed, that the problem is not with the data stream, but the clipping of EOL characters/bytes.
void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(millis());
}

...this simply sends the arduino system time in milliseconds since boot over serial comm.
To capture the stream of data, run this simple R script:
library(serial)

device = "ttyACM0" # Change this as required on specific computer
speed=9600

connection <- serialConnection("arduino", device, mode=paste0(speed,",n,8,1"),
                               translation = "auto") # alternative "crlf"
open(connection)
start_time <- as.numeric(Sys.time())*1000

while (as.numeric(Sys.time())*1000 < start_time+2500) {
  tmp <- read.serialConnection(connection)
  if (tmp != "") {
    print(tmp)
  }
}
close(connection)


There are ways around this, of course: using binary mode and parsing the data stream in R, or simply adding a special custom EOL character (e.g. '>') at the end of a line and handling data accordingly.
